# Can i perform diffrent action realted to fragment on same action bar button click

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am using slider menu in my App. now when I click on any item of drawer related fragment load.

Now I have Add button in Action bar. so I want to open new activity registration  when I click on add button click.

Now my problem is I have all fragment have different Registration form activity. so when I click on add button then whatever fragment currently selected in drawer that related registration Activity will open.

Help me I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Yes you can achieve this by dynamically adding menu to your fragment. Check this post for dynamically adding items to action bar. http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-action-items-from-within-fragments/

Comment: Please post your related code. Maybe you could get the code from your drawer click/slider

Comment: @SilvansSolanki but i just have one Add button so is there any other way to achieve this without create dynamically in each fragment.?

Comment: Are you using menu or are you using custom layout in action bar for add button?

Comment: @SilvansSolanki i am using menu.for add button

Comment: OK then load menu in every fragment instead of loading it in activity. Once you load in every fragment it will give you item selected in particular fragment only.

Comment: @SilvansSolanki i  cant get you what exactly want to say

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code in onOptionsItemSelected.

```
    if(fragment instanceOf MyFragment1){
     //Perform action related to this fragment
     }
     else if(fragment instanceOf MyFragment2){
     //Perform action related to this fragment
     }
```

Where fragment is the reference to which fragment you currently show in your activity.